# Where is GetAllUsers in membership provider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I looked at membership provider documentation and there should be two GetAllUsers method in membership provider (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getallusers ).

But when I look at methods exposed by System.Web.Security (in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll )
```

It only has one method (the one that has paging capability).

Where can I find a method to return all users from database? It seems there is no way to get list of all users or  find how many user is in the database.

**--Update**

looking at System.Web.Security, i found that SqlMembershipProvider is defined as follow:

```
public class SqlMembershipProvider : System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider
```

but this class doesn't have any public GetAllUsers() method.

How can I access its base GetAllUsers method?

Comment: And what happens when you actually call "Membership.GetAllUsers()" ?

Comment: Getting this error: Error 17 No overload for method 'GetAllUsers' takes 0 arguments

Comment: Which version & type (Original/MVC) ASP.Net are you using?

Comment: I am using MVc 3 with .Net 4.

Comment: Hi Mans, have you stumbled onto a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking in the System.Web.dll not System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll

Comment: looking at this dll, I found that:

Comment: are you not looking for System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers() ?... its in Membership, not SqlMembershipProvider.

Comment: I can not access it via SqlMembershipProvider.

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is that you have to have your membership provider, like a [SqlMembershipProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider(v=vs.110).aspx), configured in your `web.config`. The [Membership.GetAllUsers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya) method will then take the default configured `MembershipProvider` and call its method [GetAllUsers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.getallusers(v=vs.100).aspx) and pass in `0` for the current page index and `int.MaxValue` for the total records per page (as well as an `out int` to get the total records in the store).

If you are having issues calling this method check the following:

- You have the correct .net assemblies referenced

  - `System.Web`
  - `System.Web.ApplicationServices`
  - `System.Configuration`
- You have the correct namespace referenced `System.Web.Security` either

  - In your `using` statements at the top of the file
  - Directly on the type where referenced
- Your `web.config` has a registered default `MembershipProvider`

### Notes

- [SqlMembershipProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider(v=vs.110).aspx), which derives from `MembershipProvider`, is not the same type or type hierarchy as type `Membership`. So not all the methods you see on `Membership` can be found on types deriving from `MembershipProvider`.
- The type `Membership` is static and so all its members including [Membership.GetAllUsers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya) are static as well.
- The type `Membership` is there as a convenience, most of its members call through to the registered default `MembershipProvider`.

### Code sample:

```
using System.Web.Security;
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MembershipTests
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
            // same as
            var totalRecords = 0;
            users = Membership.GetAllUsers(0, int.MaxValue, out totalRecords);
            // same as (Membership.Provider gets the default registered MembershipProvider)
            users = Membership.Provider.GetAllUsers(0, int.MaxValue, out totalRecords);
        }
    }
}
```

From the documentation

> ### Remarks
>
> GetAllUsers returns the information for all membership users for an application as a collection of MembershipUser objects. Be careful when using the GetAllUsers method with very large user databases, as the resulting MembershipUserCollection in your ASP.NET page may degrade the performance of your application.

Answer (score 0):

The question is "Where is GetAllUsers in membership provider?"

The answer is that it is not in MembershipProvider.  It is in System.Web.Security.Membership

The MSDN link you provided in your question says the same thing.

The method GetAllUsers static and overloaded.

```
int userCount = 0;
MembershipUserCollection muc1 =  System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers();
MembershipUserCollection muc2 = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers(0, int.MaxValue, out userCount);
```

If you are having namespace issues, they shuffled some things around between .net 3.5 and .net 4.0

This bit me several years ago.

[.Net 4.0 System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider ambiguous reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712467/net-4-0-system-web-security-membershipprovider-ambiguous-reference)