# Error12 'Membership' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.Security.Membership' and 'testSiteV1.Model.Membership'

Tags: c#, asp.net, types, edmx

I modified a data type from int to float, then, I updated model->edms file by select the 'update model from database'.

It successfully updated but turns out with an error:Error   12  'Membership' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.Security.Membership' and 'testSiteV1.Model.Membership'.

May anyone helps me with this problem?

By the way, there is another warning says: Warning  5   The variable 'e' is declared but never used

Comment: Show the code, where the Exception is thrown

Comment: @RomanoZumbé It's not an exception but a compile error

Comment: Most likely duplicated

Comment: Ok. Whatever. Show the code where the error appears

Comment: That warning is raised when variables are declared and not used, because maybe they are declared to be used. If you have an empty `catch(Exception e)` in a `try-catch` block that could be the cause. If you click the error or the warning Visual Studio goes to the line raising the error or the warning. You should check the [MCVE] link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net 4.0 System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider ambiguous reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712467/net-4-0-system-web-security-membershipprovider-ambiguous-reference)

Answer (score 2):

You have class `Membership` in your model and also include the namespace `System.Web.Security`, which contains a class called `Membership`.

Hence the error:

> 'Membership' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.Security.Membership' and 'testSiteV1.Model.Membership'.

Remove the `using System.Web.Security;` statement if you don't need it or qualify the class usage by using the full name, i.e. `testSiteV1.Model.Membership` or `System.Web.Security.Membership`.

I can't tell you more because you don't show your code.